# Is this sentence right? - Let whoever wants to wait wait

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence

Is this sentence right?

```
Let whoever wants to wait wait.
```

I want to say, let those people who want to wait for something wait, and let me go.

Comment: It is okay but sounds very old-fashioned. We might expect this in Shakespeare's time!

Comment: Some people would insert a comma between the waits, to make it a hair less confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's okay, but it sounds a bit clumsy in my opinion.

A little change, however, will do wonders.

> Whoever wants to wait *can* wait.

Let and can do the same job, but bringing 'can' in between those two identical words makes it a smooth read, I think.